# How to delete on column of a doc in solr

Tags: solr

In my solr schema there is one dynamic field.

```
   <dynamicField name="jobs_*"  type="float"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

So I have one doc value,

```
docs: [
{
last_name: "Jain",
state_name: "rajasthan",
mobile_no: "234534564621",
id: "4",
jobs_6554: "6554",

},...]
```

Now I just want to delete one column, means jobs_6554 not the complete doc. How it can possible in solr.

So after delete, docs will be.

```
docs: [
{
last_name: "Jain",
state_name: "rajasthan",
mobile_no: "234534564621",
id: "4"
},...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `update` your doc with all the other fields having the same values and the `job_6554` having `null` or blank.

Comment: If you are using Solr 4.x, you can leverage atomic updates to just update the single column/field. Please see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates & http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22field.22http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22field.22 for more details.

Comment: Yes, I am using that atomic_updates. But I didn't know how to delete particular column, update just using null value

Comment: Thats what you should use. I did not know the version you are using.